# load iwordpress admin via iframe

Tags: wordpress, iframe

I am loading the Wordpress Admin via an iframe in  another page. For this to work have edited the default-filter.php and commented out the two lines

// add_action( 'admin_init', 'send_frame_options_header',              10, 0 );

When an update is installed I have to change this file each time.

question: is there a way to add aline via funtions.php in the child-theme so that this is done permanently?

thanks in advance

Comment: after posting the question I tried adding: remove_action( 'admin_init', 'send_frame_options_header', 10, 0 );  This solved my issue...

Answer (score 0):

Editing Core WP Files [is not recommended](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_Files). Aside from it being dangerous, any updates you make will be overwritten during updates.

The appropriate way to modify files is via `functions.php`, a plugin, or a [Must-Use Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins).

WordPress has a function called [`remove_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_action/) that you can use to unhook unwanted actions. Just make sure it's called after the action is added, and that the priority matches.

Add the following to your `functions.php` file:

```
remove_action( 'admin_init', 'send_frame_options_header', 10 );
```

Comment: thanx..slowly I start to understand ;)